# Explode string with given delimiter unless said delimiter appears between two strings/characters

Tags: php

Let's say I have a string such as the following (query from a MySQL database):
`137 ,77 ,278:214 e{34:3,32:5,33:1},277:248 e{32:5,33:1,34:3}n{Got Dirt?},323 ,443`.

I want to explode said string at each given `,` unless said character is between `{` and `}`. The proper output should look similar to the following if each line were to be printed out:

```
137 
77 
278:214 e{34:3,32:5,33:1}
277:248 e{32:5,33:1,34:3}n{Got Dirt?}
323 
443
```

How would I go about doing this most efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: I must suggest to use regular expression like @Uchiha do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `preg_split` function along with the following `regex`

```
(,)(?!(?:[^\{]*\}))
```

So your code looks like as

```
$str = "137 ,77 ,278:214 e{34:3,32:5,33:1},277:248 e{32:5,33:1,34:3}n{Got Dirt?},323 ,443";
$result = preg_split("~(,)(?!(?:[^\{]*\}))~",$str);
print_r($result);
```

**Regex Explanation :**

- `(,)`  matches the character `,` literally
- `(?!(?:[^\{]*\}))` Negative capturing group for not capturing those `,(commas)` that comes within `{}(curly braces)`

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/phSNW)

Comment: You, my good sir, are amazing. I'm not quite sure why I didn't think beforehand to utilize regex. Thank you!